# Equivalent in ruby of PHP's .= operator?

Tags: php, ruby

I'm looking to concatenate a string in a loop, like this, but in Ruby:

```
$fizz = file_get_contents($_SERVER['argv'][1]);
$output = "";
for($i=1;$i<=$fizz;$i++) {
    if($i % 3 == 0 && !($i % 5 ==0)) {
        $output .= "fizz\n";
    }
    else if($i % 5 == 0 && !($i % 3 ==0)) {
        $output .= "buzz\n";
    }
    else if($i % 3 == 0 && $i % 5 == 0) {
        $output .= "FizzBuzz\n";
    }
}
print $output;
?>
```

I'm also interested in finding out what the name of the ".=" type operator is called so I can Google search these things better.

Using Ruby 1.8.6.

Comment: It is called a "string concatenation operator"

Comment: @DGM string concat using += is painfully slow compared to <<. You're talking about duplicating the string everytime. [Look at this](https://gist.github.com/1001800)

Comment: If you are doing 100000 of them maybe.  If you have one or two, it's no big deal.  Profile your own work, and find the real bottlenecks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for Ruby's `String#<<`.

So, your code might look like this:

```
variable << "fizz\n"
```

Here is the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001173) for the << (aka concat) method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ruby, but a quick search for `Ruby String Concatenation` (the operator is not a really an operator (PHP is just.. special, and not necessarily the good kind), it's called string concatenation) gives the following:

`myString = "Welcome " + "to " + "Ruby!"` - Standard concatenation across most languages.

`myString = "Welcome " "to " "Ruby!"` - Omits + sign

`myString = "Welcome " << "to " << "Ruby!"` - c++ `cout` style.

The content of `myString` will all be `"Welcome to Ruby"`.

Maybe you could even do `+=` (equivilant to `.=`)

Watch out for freeze strings.. apparently.

More info: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_String_Concatenation_and_Comparison

Answer (score 0):

Is there a real reason you need to solve it this way? This can be expressed in Ruby like so:

```
(1..100).each do |number|
  if number % 15 == 0
    puts "#{number} FizzBuzz"
  elsif number % 5 == 0
    puts "#{number} Buzz"
  elsif number % 3 == 0
    puts "#{number} Fizz"
  end
end
```

Using (1..100) is a range which mixes in `Enumerable` so we can iterate over the items.

Answer (score 0):

If the fizzbuzz problem allows for printing all numbers (as some interpretations do), then here's a variant of Caley Woods example above, showcasing the way case statements return values

```
(1..100).each do |number|
  puts number.to_s << case 0
   when number % 15
     " FizzBuzz"
   when number % 5
     " Buzz"
   when number % 3
     " Fizz"
   else
     ""
   end
end
```